# Changing column value based on another column using vba in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro button that will help me update the the value in the AE column to "N" if the value in the same row of the H column is "REPO".

I am not sure why my code doesn't work properly and just seems to select the AE column when I run it instead of changing the values to "N"

```
Sub Change_Repo_Risk_to_N()     

    Sheets("expo").Select    
    Dim LastRow As Long    
    Dim i As Long    
    LastRow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow           
        If Range("H" & i).Value = "REPO" Then    
            Range("AE" & i).Value = "N"    
        End If   
    Next i      

End Sub
```

Comment: Works just fine with me. Maybe running through the code line by line (use `F8`) may help you to locate the problem? Also, try to avoid `Select` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Perhaps the ranges you have in mind aren't actually inside `Sheets("expo")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably mistake due to one if these 3:

- Lack of `Trim()`
- Lack of `UCase()` (`Option Compare Text` is an alternative of this one)
- `Select()` is too slow and does not refer correctly to the worksheet ([try to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba))

Try this one:

```
Sub ChangeRepoRiskToN()
 
    With Worksheets("expo")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim i As Long
    
        lastRow = .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                If Trim(UCase(.Range("H" & i).Value)) = "REPO" Then
                    .Range("AE" & i).Value = "N"
                End If
            Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice! I think the Trim function was what I was missing! Everything works fine now :)